# Не работает кнопка в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

делал кнопку для очищения корзины, копка работает сам код работает. Кнопку инициализирует оп классу. Но... если я устанавливаю этот класс на кнопку которая находиться в модальном окне, ничего не происходит и корзина не очищается. Помогите пожалуйста в решении этой проблемы, я только начал учить js, и front в общем.

`код`    https://codepen.io/TraenGO/pen/abLwJVJ `код`

Код в js. строка кнопки для удаления [173, 184, 219-222], Модальное окна находиться с 142 строки, временная кнопка на которой стоит класс удаления [unikalniy-class] находиться на 140 строчке.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что вы пытаетесь навесить на кнопку обработчик в тот момент, когда этой кнопки ещё не существует - Vue её не отрисовала. Поскольку вы работаете в Vue, то и навешивать обработчики нужно средствами Vue.

```
<button class="unikalniy-class button-yes" @click="resetCart" id="btn-yes">

methods: {
    resetCart: function(){
        this.showModal = false;
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("reset-сart", {
        }));
    }
}
```